# How to pivot on multiple rows and create a calculated column in pandas at the same time

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Item | Category | Price | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | First | 1 | 5 |
| A | Second | 2 | 6 |
| A | Third | 2 | 6 |
| B | First | 2 | 5 |
| B | Second | 3 | 6 |
| B | Third | 4 | 9 |

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
input = [{'Item':'A', 'Category':'First', 'Price': 1, 'Quantity':5}, {'Item':'A', 'Category':'Second', 'Price': 2, 'Quantity':6}, {'Item':'A', 'Category':'Third', 'Price': 2, 'Quantity':6},
{'Item':'B', 'Category':'First', 'Price': 2, 'Quantity':5}, {'Item':'B', 'Category':'Second', 'Price': 3, 'Quantity':6}, {'Item':'B', 'Category':'Third', 'Price': 4, 'Quantity':9}]
df = pd.DataFrame(input)
```

and I want to pivot the category so that the quantity of each item falling into each category appears as a separate column. I want to also create a new column after pivoting consisting of the sum of all Price*Quantity.

It should look something like this:

| Item | First | Second | Third | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 6 | 6 | 27 |
| B | 5 | 6 | 9 | 64 |

I managed to do the pivot using this but I can't create the calculated column after pivoting.

```
df.pivot(index="Item", columns="Category", values="Quantity")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

Firstly calculate the Total:

```
df['Total']=df['Price']*df['Quantity']
```

via `pivot_table()` and `groupby()`:

```
out=df.pivot_table(index="Item", columns="Category", values="Quantity").assign(Total=df.groupby('Item')['Total'].sum())
```

OR

via `crosstab()` and `groupby()`:

```
out=pd.crosstab(df['Item'],df['Category'],df[['Quantity']],aggfunc='sum').assign(Total=df.groupby('Item')['Total'].sum())
```

If needed use:

```
out.columns.names=[None]
out=out.reset_index()
```

Now If you print `out` you will get your expected output

Comment: Thanks, nice this is working for me. Should have thought about doing the total calculation in a separate step.